Скрипт не создаёт текстовый файл и не пишет в нём. python
with open("hello.txt", "a+", encoding='utf-8') as file:
   file.write("hello work\n")
   print("Файл изменен")

Оно просто не работает, даже ошибок не выводит, хотя в консоли пишет "Файл изменен"

отступы забыли?

не отступы есть, откопировал плохо просто

Откуда вы знаете, что код не работает? Файл не появляется? Файл не изменяется?

Если вы сделаете так, с абсолютным путем:
with open("D:\\hello.txt",

то увидите свой файл. Он создаётся и в вашем случае, только вы не знаете где - в текущей активной папке.
(У меня в данный момент это C:\Users\MBo\AppData\Local\Temp)

О, благодарю, теперь буду знать

лишний слеш после диска

@SeVlad, не лишний, без него будет "SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\h'". Нужно или экранировать обратные слэши, или использовать r-строки, или вообще прямые слэши использовать.

@insolor а, тут надо экранировать. Ок. И спасибо.
